# Default values for crosstab results

Tags: postgresql, pivot, coalesce

I'm trying to write my first crosstab query in Postgres. Some of the results have no entries and so the rows that are returned have null entries. How do I set a default value for those entries?

Here is a row that is returned:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------------------+-----
username                        | some name
some_column_name_1              | 2
some_column_name_2              |
```

Here is my crosstab query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM crosstab( 'select username, stage, count from some_view order by 1,2') 
     AS final_result(username TEXT,
         "some_column_name_1" BIGINT,
         "some_column_name_2" BIGINT,
);
```

I've tried little things like this with no luck:

```
"some_column_name_1" BIGINT 0
"some_column_name_1" BIGINT default 0
"some_column_name_1" BIGINT set default 0
```

Comment: Please **[Edit]** your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables in question adding the desired output. Those answering need a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486).

Comment: Have you tried to use coalesce:  http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-coalesce/   ?

Comment: Bingo! Coalesce was the word I was missing. Post this as the answer and I'll mark it as correct! @AMG

Comment: SELECT username, COALESCE(some_column_name_1, 0), COALESCE(some_column_name_2, 0)
FROM crosstab( 'select username, stage, count from some_view order by 1,2') 
     AS final_result(username TEXT,
         "some_column_name_1" BIGINT,
         "some_column_name_2" BIGINT,
);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**More importantly**, if ...

> some of the results have no entries

You **need** `crosstab(text, text)` - the variant with **2** input parameters instead of `crosstab(text)` you are using now to avoid incorrect results. Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

So, assuming the respective values in the column `stage` are 'some_column_name_1' and 'some_column_name_2':

```
SELECT username
     , COALESCE(col1, 0) AS some_column_name_1  -- sets default for NULL
     , COALESCE(col2, 0) AS some_column_name_2
FROM   crosstab(
   'select username, stage, count from some_view order by 1,2'
  , $$VALUES ('some_column_name_1'), ('some_column_name_2')$$  -- !!!
   ) AS final_result (username text, col1 bigint, col2 bigint);
```

And `COALESCE` provides the default value for NULL that you asked for - like [AMG commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210885/crosstab-default-value-postgres#comment413409_210885).

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this second parameter variant Erwin!